# jquery.maskedinput programmatically set value and apply mask?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I'm using [DigitalBush's MaskedInput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) jquery plugin. I have a simple input box for a phone number:

```
$('#txt_PhoneNumber').mask('(999) 999-9999');
```

Sometimes the field is programmatically filled with a non-formated number such as `5551234567`. How can I notify the mask input to apply it's mask to "beautify" it's new input?

Comment: Try `$('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('input')`

Comment: Just tried that and triggering `'change'` but nothing.

Comment: It does seem that if I reapply the mask that it will "beautify" but if the data is wrong it clears the field.

Comment: One more try: `.trigger('keypress.mask')` Here's how it binds in the source: `.bind("keypress.mask", keypressEvent)`

Comment: Still no effect. I'm in IE10 if it makes any difference.

Comment: From viewing the source, it looks like it works off the keypress event, but doesn't do anything if a keycode isn't sent in. It would probably be easiest to look at that keypress event, figure out what actually does the masking, moving it to it's own function, and exposing the function as a "refresh"

Comment: I know the question is very old, but as there have been changes in the library I will leave here how this should be done today:
`$('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('blur.mask')`

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps things have changed since this question was asked, because Jason P's first suggestion appears to work now.

```
$('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('input');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/450v79zy/)

The following should work too:

```
$('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('paste');
```

Comment: $('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('input');
works for me.

Comment: If the phone number value is blank, .trigger('input') leaves it as "(___) ___-____" instead of blank. Reapplying the mask with .mask('(999) 999-9999') does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to refresh by calling `.trigger("focus")` : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et8kC/)

The downside: it highlights the input.

Comment: Really strange behaviour, i changed your code ( not using Math.random, just simple text ) , and it stoped working
`$("#txt_PhoneNumber").val(function(index,val){ 
 return 10 * 10; 
}).trigger("focus");`

Comment: I need to support IE 11 and Chrome v64.0.  In IE 11 .trigger('input') is all that is needed.  In Chrome 64.0 I find I need .trigger('input').trigger('focus').

Answer (score 0):

After set the value, call the jQuery trigger fn.

```
$('#txt_PhoneNumber').trigger('keyup');
```

Works for me.

jquery.mask.js
@version: v1.14.16

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically change masking

```
            if (is_loose == "True") {                   
                $("#it_qty").removeAttr("data-inputmask","'mask': '9{0,20}'");
                $("#it_qty").attr("data-inputmask", "'mask': '9{0,20}.9{0,2}'");

                $("[data-mask]").inputmask();// if necessary

            } else {
                $("#chk_is_loose").prop("checked", false);
                $("#it_qty").removeAttr("data-inputmask", "'mask': '9{0,20}.9{0,2}'");
                $("#it_qty").attr("data-inputmask", "'mask': '9{0,20}'");
                $("[data-mask]").inputmask();// if necessary
            }
```